# How to hide specific TD borders in a TABLE using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, borderless

I want to have some TDs in a table without border. Here is what I've tried:

CSS

```
.calendar-noBorder {
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
}

.calendar-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.calendar-table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="calendar-table">
    <tr>
        <td class="calendar-noBorder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td> 1 </td>
        <td> 2 </td>
        <td> 3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="calendar-noBorder">&nbsp;</td>
        <td> a </td>
        <td> b </td>
        <td> c </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> aaaaaa</td>
        <td> b </td>
        <td> c </td>
        <td> d </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bwudg7fn/)

I want the TDs with noBorderTD class to have no border and the others to have borders. I'd like to avoid to specify a class using "class=" on every bordered TDs.

What's the best way to do it clean ?

Comment: You need to check at least that one, about "border conflict resolution": http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order of applying styles was wrong. The correct order is:

```
.calendar-table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td.calendar-noBorder {
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
}


.calendar-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Explanation: First specify the borders for all the td, then remove the specific td borders which are not needed.

See the fiddle: "https://jsfiddle.net/bwudg7fn/1/"

Comment: This is even better than brute forcing it with `!important` as I did :D

Comment: Thanks :) Ya use of !important is discouraged unless no other option is left.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
border:none;
```

Use -

```
border:0;
```

on the TD classes

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.calendar-noBorder {
    border: none!important;
    background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwudg7fn/2/