# How to hide or remove specific td borders

Tags: html, css

I know this was answered before, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335229/how-to-hide-specific-td-borders-in-a-table-using-css) post, but I've been trying to apply that to my code and I don't know what is wrong.

This is what I'm trying to get:

[image: IWantThis]

This is what I have:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.noborders > td {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ye</td>
      <td>ye</td>
      <td>ye</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ye</td>
      <td>ye</td>
      <td>ye</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="noborders">
      <td>no</td>
      <td>no</td>
      <td>no</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this is what I've gotten with that code:

[image: wrongtable]

I tried with `table{border-bottom:0}` in css part, this almost works and I could see what is wrong is the entire table border that can't be removed from the third row when I use `border: none` on third row td's.

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just change your css for .noborders > td by this

```
.noborders > td{
       border-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-style: hidden;
    border-right-style: hidden;
    border-left-style: hidden;
}
```

the whole will be like

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.noborders > td{
       border-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-style: hidden;
    border-right-style: hidden;
    border-left-style: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>ye</td><td>ye</td><td>ye</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ye</td><td>ye</td><td>ye</td></tr>
        <tr class="noborders"><td>no</td><td>no</td><td>no</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Pancreatico you should use inspect element feature of browser i do it by that best of luck to you for future !

Answer (score 2):

Don't use border on whole table. You can use border on specific columns.

Try this.

```css
.bor{
  border:solid 1px #000;
  
 }
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="bor">Ye</td>
        <td class="bor">Ye</td>
        <td class="bor">Ye</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="bor">Ye</td>
        <td class="bor">Ye</td>
        <td class="bor">Ye</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>no</td>
        <td>no</td>
        <td>no</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: ty so much, >< i'm very new on this.

Answer (score 1):

now here is the solution

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
/*use this class */
.noborders{
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>ye</td><td>ye</td><td>ye</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ye</td><td>ye</td><td>ye</td></tr>
        <tr class="noborders"><td>no</td><td>no</td><td>no</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```